# Could there be any language issue with a ODBC in R with an Access DB?

Tags: r, database, ms-access, odbc, nanodbc

I am using an R Script which connects to a local Access database. For that, I used the 'odbc' package in R and created an odbc Driver in Windows. It works well on my machine.
The issue I have is, that it can't connect to the database when running the script on a **foreign** computer with different language settings than English. Both machines are running Windows 64-bit with Access and R on 64-bit. Running following Code:

```
library(odbc)

con <- dbConnect(odbc::odbc(), "AccessDB")
```

**results in following error message:**

> Error in connection_info(ptr) : nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1072:

I didn't find a solution yet, I am thinking of using another database.

Comment: Look at the RODBC package.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in the odbc library. I'd go through official support channels for that, not Stack Overflow

Comment: this has been fixed on the github, see: https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc/issues/325 - einar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I received the same error today on a setup that usually works. After downgrading the odbc-package to 1.1.6, it works fine again.